# How to build an array of all the input classes within a div?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having trouble figuring out how to set arrays, on pageload, that contains all the class names and id names of every input within a div with the id of boardinput.

```
<div id="boardinput">
    <input id='R1C1' class="blank" maxlength="1" />
    <input id='R1C2' class="tw" maxlength="1" />
    <input id='R1C3' class="blank" maxlength="1" />
    <input id='R1C4' class="tw" maxlength="1" />
    <input id='R1C5' class="dl" maxlength="1" />
    <input id='R1C6' class="blank" maxlength="1" />
</div>
```

so array1 = ["R1C1","R1C2","R1C3","R1C4","R1C4","R1C5","R1C6"]

and array2 = ["blank","tw","blank","tw","dl","blank"]

I want to do this so that I can revert back to the original class and id after a change has been made. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What kind of change is going to change the id or class?

Comment: I have a onblur event changing the class if the input.value is not null so a different style will be applied.  The problem I was having was that if I changed the input back to null, the original class or id was not remembered.  There might be a better way than storing the original values in arrays but I cannot think of how.

Comment: While @paislee doesn't state it in his answer, php is not the way to do this - the javascript he proposed IS the right way to do it.  FYI, moving to jQuery would be a good move, as it makes this kind of code trivial to write and eliminates cross-browser compatibility issues.  ADDITIONALLY, the correct answer to your ISSUE (which is different than your question) involves using addClass and removeClass functionality, rather than removing/replacing the class.  See http://api.jquery.com/addClass/ to see how simple it is with jQuery.

Comment: @cale_b I am sure there is a much better way to solve my issue. I am very new to this stuff so any and all the advice is appreciated. I have multiple original classes that differ because the original styles differ between various inputs based on their class. I can only assume that removeClass will completely remove the class?  if so, I would lose all my style instead of reverting back to what it was before? I will be learning jquery soon, hopefully, once I get a better understanding of javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't ask for jQuery, here's a pure JS solution:

```
var inputs = document.getElementById('boardinput')
                     .getElementsByTagName('input');

var input_IDs = new Array();
var input_classes = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    input_IDs[i] = inputs[i].id;
    input_classes[i] = inputs[i].className;
}
```

- [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/paislee/vLDeg/1)

Comment: @narek.gevorgyan If you mean "cross-browser compatible", then yes. Are YOU sure the OP knows what jQuery is?

Comment: He asked for a solution respecting only input elements in a div with the id "boardinput". Maybe you should consider this in your solution?

Comment: Thanks, I am not quite familiar with jquery, though I linked to it in my HTML to try the other solutions, and I received an error that input.attr was not a function. This here pure JS solution worked great. Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery. This code must work

```
var array1 = [];
var array2 = [];
$('#boardinput').children().each(function(index, element){
  array1.push(element.attr('id'));
  array2.push(element.attr('class'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better way of reverting the attributes but here's how you would insert them into an array using jQuery:

```
$('#boardinput > input').each(function(index, input){
  array1.push(input.attr('id'));
  array2.push(input.attr('class'));
});
```